# RestKit loadObjectsAtResourcePath not working

Tags: ios, restkit

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting absolutely nothing in behaviour when I make a call to loadObjectsAtResourcePath? Nothing in the logs, none of the delegates that I define on my class are called at all.

```
    RKObjectMapping* roundMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Round class]];
        [roundMapping mapKeyPath:@"Id" toAttribute:@"id"];
        [roundMapping mapKeyPath:@"Name" toAttribute:@"name"];
        [roundMapping mapKeyPath:@"Description" toAttribute:@"description"];
        [roundMapping mapKeyPath:@"NumberOfPlayers" toAttribute:@"numberOfPlayers"];
        [roundMapping mapKeyPath:@"PlayerLimit" toAttribute:@"playerLimit"];
        [roundMapping mapKeyPath:@"Url" toAttribute:@"url"];

        [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:roundMapping];

        [RKObjectManager sharedManager].client.baseURL = [RKURL URLWithString:@"http://69.999.150.71:1023/service/"];

        [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/lobby2" delegate:self];

        //[RKClient clientWithBaseURLString:@"http://69.999.150.71:1023/service/"];

        //[[RKClient sharedClient] get:@"/lobby?format=JSON" delegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
    [alert show];
    NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Loaded payload: %@", [response bodyAsString]);
}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects
{
    NSLog(@"Loaded: %@", objects);
}
```

Comment: is the parent object defined as the delegate so it can response to the method calls?

Answer (score 0):

In your @interface are you using `<RKObjectLoaderDelegate>` ?  ObjectLoader won't get messaged unless that is implemented.